# Problem with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have just installed hibernate. When I typed hibernate the first time, the system seamed to hibernate properly (displayed a message about dumping memory, then shut down). But no it no longer boots up anymore.

I managed to boot into the system using an older version of the kernel in grub boot manager, but cannot boot normally with my lastest version.

I'm using ubuntu 13.10

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot with the same kernel you hibernated, but in recovery  mode.  Then, when the system is loaded, just reboot. This should remove the lock.

About why the hibernation failed, can't help you without more information. Maybe you can add something when you manage to boot back normally.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. However, the system does not boot EVEN in recovery mode using my lastest kernel. WIth older kernel it boots both in normal AND recovery mode.

Btw the last message displayed is: - running /scripts/local-premount resume libgcrypt version 1.5.0

Then nothing more happens even after waiting a few minutes...

Is there a way to remove the lock or the hibernate file ?

Comment: As for "why did it fail", I think I know ! I just read you need to have more swap than yoiu have RAM. I only have 4Gb swap for a total of 24 Gb of RAM. The reason is I actually never need swap at all with 24 Gb of RAM... Now I need to revert that hibernate thing...

Comment: i disabled cryptswap, i then ran the command: sudo update-initramfs -u . I can finally boot up normally. I uninstalled hibernate and will never use it again !!

Comment: Glad you sorted it. You didn't need it to uninstall hibernate, but I suppose it's OK if you are not going to use it.

Comment: @user2968688 I see no reason for it to not work with cryptswap, it seems like a bug or limitation..